# How do I change the template .hgignore used for new repositories?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When I create a new repository, I can ask TortoiseHG to give me a .hgignore file. Is there a way that I can customise what that file will look like, rather than having to go and get one manually from somewhere every time?

Comment: Duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785609/would-like-to-create-some-defaults-for-my-hgignore-files-in-tortoisehg-mercurial

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate. The answers in that question are probably the right solution what Neil wants, but he's asking how to modify the template for TortoiseHG's .hgignore file (which it appears to be impossible)

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, put still popped up as the first result on google, so here is an update:

In the TortoiseHg settings under the tab TortoiseHg users can specify the path of a Repo Skeleton. You can put your predefined .hgignore there, and it will be automatically copied during hg init.

See also:
[#3569 Allow user-defined default .hgignore file when creating a new repository](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues/3569) 
[TortoiseHG Docs](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=Repo%20Skeleton#tortoisehg)

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim already said in his comment, apparently it's not possible to do this.

Take a look at the following issue from TortoiseHG's bug tracker:
[#966 Include some reasonable defaults in .hgignore on repo creation](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg-hgtk/-/issues/966)

Quotes from this link, both by Steve Borho (THG project lead):

> This topic comes up on the Mercurial mailing list once a year or so and Matt always shoots it down. There is already support for user level ignore files; one could add these globs to a global file and be done with it.

and:

> If a user has files or directories that they always want to ignore, they can add those to a global ignore file without having to introduce any new behaviors in THG.

So putting the things you always want ignored in a user-global ignore file seems to be the only option (even though it's not exactly what you're asking for):

- [Would like to create some defaults for my .hgignore files in TortoiseHG/Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1785609/6884)
  *(the question that I posted in my comment above)*
- [Global hgignore usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8300470/6884)